# Is postgresql appropriate for organizing documents?

Tags: database, postgresql, document

I work as a "non-computer" Engineer at a small company.  I've dabbled in Python, but am otherwise completely new to programming.  I'm interested in relational databases to make accessing records more efficient, and am interested in learning postgresql.  Here's the rub.  We have many document records in the form of images, pdfs, microsoft word, and excel documents that are organized in folders and sub-folders.  Co-workers are using Windows 7 and 10.  Postgres seems perfect to store data, but I need to be able to tie back any database records (perhaps link) to the "source" document organized in the folders (so documents will be accessible outside of the database).  Is there an easy way to do this in Postgres, or should I learn something else?

Comment: This question is not technically focused enough to receive a satisfying answer. If I understood you right, you want to store references to files in the database. That would mean to store the path og the file (something like `D:\mydir\myfile.xls`) in a `text` column in the database.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to store the documents in the file system rather than the database in tables & columns.

Metadata of the documents, file path can be stored in the relational database.

Example: Alfresco uses PostgreSQL to store `path, metadata, retention period, user-group management`, .... And it uses file system to store the documents (images, PDF, Audio, Video...)